# How to get all rows in one table that imply to a row in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:
Suppliers:

```
Id Name
1  Dan
2  John
```

Products:

```
Id Name C_Id
1  AAA 1
2  BBB 2
3  CCC 1
```

What I want to do is iterating over each supplier (once), and print it's products. Something like that:

```
{c.name} supllies {p.id} {p.name} 
Dan supplies 1 AAA and 3 CCC 
John supplies 2 BBB
```

What would be right way to fetch this data from the server? because now I use 2 loops, and I think there should be an more efficient way.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT Id,Name FROM Suppliers")))
    $id = $row["id"];
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT Id,Name FROM Products WHERE C_Id = $id")))
       push each $row2 in $array
    print $array for each $row1
```

Thank you

Comment: try this query: `Select Suppliers.Id as S_Id, Suppliers.Name as S_Name, Products.Id as P_Id, Products.Name as P_Name
FROM Suppliers, Products
WHERE Products.C_Id = Suppliers.Id`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use join:**

```
SELECT Suppliers.Id S_ID, Suppliers.Name S_NAME, Products.Id P_ID, Products.Name P_NAME FROM Suppliers LEFT JOIN Products ON Suppliers.Id = Products.C_Id
```